# How can I query NEO4J for duplicate numbers? If the number 919360123 is in the first column and is repeated in the second column in a different row

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-ogm, neo4j-apoc

How do I extract duplicate numbers in columns by querying in NEO4J. For example, if the number 919360123 is in the first column and is repeated in the second column in a different row, what is the appropriate receipt to extract the numbers shared between the columns

[image]

Comment: Your question has nothing obvious to do with neo4j. Can you update your question to indicate exactly what you are trying to do with a neo4j DB?

Answer (score 1):

For this you can use the apoc collection procedures, like the intersection one :

```
WITH ['1', '2', '3'] AS a, ['2'] as b
RETURN apoc.coll.intersection(a, b)
```

So in your example, you can make a `collect` of the columns, and then use the procedure.